# Fail to unlock PDF-File with ghostscript

Tags: php, ghostscript

I am trying to unlock the password of a PDF-File with ghostscript but it is not working.

If I run it through command line it works perfectly. Can anyone please guide me what the problem is and how to fix it.

My code:

```
shell_exec("gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=/var/www/html/rpkfiles/Hands_on_Trade1.pdf /var/www/html/rpkfiles/Hands_on_Trade.pdf");
```

Comment: What's the error message displayed (if any)?

Comment: if i try to open the new file(converted) it is showing white page... no error msg is comming.

Comment: If the same command can be executed from your command line and it works, it looks like it's involving the permissions of the file.

Comment: Still the same problem? You see, when you execute the command you run with different permissions than PHP. This is why I suggested it could be the permissions. One test for example, would be you removing all the permissions to a certain PDF file and trying to use the command on it to see the output.

Comment: What message do you get on the console ? There *will* be something there, though I'd recommend you drop the -dQUIET while trying to debug a problem, the last thing you want to do is hide stuff. Note that Ghostscript produces a new file, it does not 'unlock' the old file! And the setup you have here only works for files with an empty user password.

Comment: okk thanks for the advice...